# SYBASE: SQL call to find first available (island) ID's

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to return an ordered list of specific length of available customerIDs.

**for example:**

I need to find the FIRST 5 unused customerIDs between 1500 and 3000

```
Table= customer
Column= customerIDs
customerIDs value's= 1500,1502,1503,1507,1508
Return desired= 1501,1504,1505,1506,1509
```

I am running an old version of SYBASE that does not have "TOP" command. So far I have found the following Query to give me the next available customerID(1501), but do not know how to modify it to return the first 5 results rather then just 1.

```
set rowcount 5 
SELECT  MIN(c.customerIDs )+1 AS NextID 
FROM customer c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT NULL 
    FROM customer cu 
    WHERE cu.customerIDs =c.customerIDs +1 
    AND cu.customerIDs >1500)
  AND c.customerIDs <3000
```

Comment: I don't see how you might do this other than to write a stored proc and loop over values from 1500 to 3000, or alternately populate a table with those values and get the non-matching ones through a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming you are using `set rowcount 5`, this will limit the query to return 5 results.

However, you are using `MIN` which will for sure return only 1 record. I think you want to use

```
set rowcount 5 
SELECT  c.customerIDs +1 AS NextID 
FROM customer c 
WHERE (c.customerIDs + 1 BETWEEN 1500 and 3000)
  AND c.customerIDs + 1 NOT IN (SELECT c2.customerIDs
                   FROM customer c2)
ORDER BY c.customerIDs
```

Comment: ok so this is closer.... but that is only returning the first ID for each gap in IDs...it may work in the example above but when there is a gap of say 5 IDs it will grab the first and move on to the first ID of the next gap, etc.

Comment: so for example if customerIDs value's= 1500,1501,1502,1510,1511,1525,1526 it only returns= 1503, 1512, 1527

Comment: @JavaBeast I see, try with new one. Also, please delete the previous comment as moderator does not like extended discussion in comments.

Comment: The new query gave exact same result.

Comment: I also updated question for the scenario that breaks this answer. thanks.

Comment: @JavaBeast I need to go to work, I'll try something else later if no one solved your issue... You might want to check using the `CONNECT BY` to simulate a loop...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worked example, expanding on [David Faber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236090/david-faber)'s comment:

```
-- Create a temp table with all possible IDs
declare @min int, @max int
select @min = 1500, @max = 3000

create table #all_ids (id int)
insert #all_ids select @min

-- Keep doubling the number of rows until the limit is reached
while (select max(id) from #all_ids) < @max
begin
    insert #all_ids
    select id + (select count(*) from #all_ids)
    from #all_ids
    where id + (select count(*) from #all_ids) <= @max
end

-- Now find the 5 missing IDs by joining to the customer table on customerIDs, and only returning rows
-- where there is no match, i.e. customerIDs is null
set rowcount 5
select tmp.id
from #all_ids tmp
left join customer c
    on tmp.id = c.customerIDs
where c.customerIDs is null
order by tmp.id
set rowcount 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately this is not going to work for me, I would need a select statement for my purpose (if possible). Hopefully this will help someone else in the future out though :)

Comment: The bit that returns the data **is** a select statement - I guess you mean you need ONLY a select statement.  I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

One trick to do this is to generate a sequence on the fly from the master..spt_values table, which is usually available in most servers. 
This table contains a natural sequence that can be joined to itself to generate an even larger sequence. Example:

```
create table #customer (customerID int)
go
insert #customer (customerID) values (1500)
insert #customer (customerID) values (1502)
insert #customer (customerID) values (1503)
insert #customer (customerID) values (1507)
insert #customer (customerID) values (1508)
go
set rowcount 5
select customerID
from (
  -- Generate a sequence of 1500-3000
  select 1500 + p2.number * 1000 + p1.number as customerID
  from 
    master..spt_values p1
  , master..spt_values p2
  where 
      p1.type = 'P'
  and p2.type = 'P'
  and p1.number between 0 and 999
  and p2.number between 0 and 1
  and p2.number * 1000 + p1.number <= 1500) seq
where customerID not in (select customerID from #customer)
order by 1
set rowcount 0
go
```

Returns:

```
 customerID    
 ------------- 
 1501          
 1504          
 1505          
 1506          
 1509
```